# Creating a File in a new Directory

Tags: java

I came up with the follwing code...my Document is not created.
I dont get any Error messages. Regarding the Java API i did everything in the right order. The directory is created in the right way...so i dont have to worry about that.

Anyone got an idea or an hint where to look at?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String path = null;
    String destination = "/myfolder/test/" + createRandomPath(path);
    try {
        boolean status;
        status = new File(destination).mkdir();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fehler: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    File document = new File(destination + "temp.docx");

    //Edit: Here is the solution..Thank you
    document.createNewFile();

  }
  static String createRandomPath(String path){
     UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
     path = uuid.toString().replace('-', 'A').substring(0,9);
     System.out.println(path);
     return path;
  }
```

Comment: what does createRandomPath(path), where path = null, do for you?

Comment: One more hint: I'd rename the local variable 'Document' to a lower case name. Otherwise people think, 'Document' is a class and 'createNewFile()' a static method on that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to call createNewFile() to, err, create a new file on disk if that's what you're asking.

so you need code of the form:

```
File f = new File("C:\\temp\\newfile.txt");
//new file does not exist on disk yet
f.createNewFile();
//f should be created on disk now
```

Comment: you are right..:-) arrrgh got the answer the whole time in front of my nose and couldnt find it.

Comment: i added your answer to my code... with a "Solution" Comment. Thank you..Upvote

Answer (score 1):

The `File Document...` line creates an instance of the `File` class in memory. As James B says, you need to then create the file, perhaps with something like this:

```
File doc = new File(destination + "temp.docx");
doc.createNewFile();
```

(Remember to wrap this in a `try... catch` as you will have to trap `IOException`)

Answer (score 0):

I have modified and executed at my end, I have modified the path and executed
""c:\myfolder\test" + createRandomPath(path);"
It works.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String path = null;
    String destination = "c:\\myfolder\\test" + createRandomPath(path);
    try {
        boolean status;
        status = new File(destination).mkdir();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Fehler: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    File document = new File(destination + "temp.doc");

    //Edit: Here is the solution..Thank you
    document.createNewFile();

  }
  static String createRandomPath(String path){
     UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
     path = uuid.toString().replace('-', 'A').substring(0,9);
     System.out.println(path);
     return path;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the below code. It will work

```
public class Test1{
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception
    {
        String path = null;
        String destination = "/myfolder/test/" + createRandomPath(path);
        try
        {
            boolean status;
            status = new File(destination).mkdirs();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Fehler: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        File document = new File(destination + "/temp.docx");

        //Edit: Here is the solution..Thank you
        document.createNewFile();

    }

    static String createRandomPath(String path)
    {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        path = uuid.toString().replace('-', 'A').substring(0, 9);
        System.out.println(path);
        return path;
    }

}
```

When i run above code on netbeans it created file "temp.docx" in "C:\myfolder\test\b75ba657A"